# How to get the data of a video from youtube in javascript

Tags: javascript, video, youtube

I am trying to get the data of a video from youtube using youtube data API but I am getting the 403 forbidden error like below

```
{"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"global","reason":"forbidden","message":"Forbidden"}],"code":403,"message":"Forbidden"}}
```

### What I am trying is:

```
      var apiKey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";   
        var  videoId = "s7wmiS2mSXY";

        var gUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=" + videoId + "&key=" + apiKey + "&part=snippet,statistics,contentDetails";

$http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: gUrl
      }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        console.log('sucess call.', response);
      }, function errorCallback(err) {
        console.log('Error while saving this Video Id details in videoId.', err);
      });
```

While I copied the whole url `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=s7wmiS2mSXY&key=XXXXmyApiKeyXXXXX&part=snippet,statistics,contentDetails` and tried in a new tab, I am getting the json object in browser but when I tried it on my localhost using $http.get I am getting the 403 forbidden error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you getting a CORS error in the console?

Comment: I tried this using jQuery and it worked fine for me.

Comment: in the console it is showing only `{"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"global","reason":"forbidden","message":"Forbidden"}],"code":403,"message":"Forbidden"}}` this error in the errorCallback function @evolutionxbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely your problem is with your key if you are getting a 403 error. I would go back and check it's right. I tried recreating your problem with jquery but it seemed to work just fine. My code was:

```
var apiKey = "xxxxxxx my_key xxxxxx";
var videoId = "s7wmiS2mSXY";

var gUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=" + videoId + "&key=" + apiKey + "&part=snippet,statistics,contentDetails";

$.get(gUrl, function (data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: may i know the reason why iam getting that error?@brennanenanen

Comment: Apart from the if the key was wrong, it should work fine. As I have shown above when I tried it using majorly your code it worked without problems. I suggest you try, like I did, with jquery as well.